# Creation of External Tables - Automation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, external-tables

I was wondering if you help me with the following question and give me some guidelines. Before telling me that it is more of a google question, I would like to say that I am new to this topic which makes googling a bit hard.

Question:
I was wondering if it is possible to automate the creation of an external table by reading the first row of a txt file? I was reading something about UTL_FILE however I am not sure if it is correct approach. I am interested into this as sometimes I have txt files with 50+ columns and the manual creation of such an external table would take pretty long.

Any help or guidelines would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I were you, I would use a scripting language to parse a file and to generate an SQL script. Your username suggests that you're familiar with VBA, so, probably you can accomplish this task in VB. This way you won't have to deal with`UTL_FILE` and associated issues.

Comment: If you still want to do this in PL/SQL you'll need to go through [the documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069). First, try some examples. Then split your task into steps: (1) read a file; (2) parse it; (3) generate SQL. Work through these steps one-by-one. Currently, your question is too broad, because it's unclear which particular step is giving you problems.

Comment: It's possible to find out the column names from the first line, but what about the data types? Are they all known in advance?

Comment: @defaultlocale thank you for the documentation and for the tip. You are right that it is a bit broad. I will do try to split the task for myself and yes I would like to stick to PL/SQL as I want to get used to it.

Comment: @wolφi, the data types are known yes, Varchar2 would be enough.

Comment: @VBABegginer Good luck! Please, note that `UTL_FILE` works with files on the database **server**. If you want to work with a client-side file, you'll need to learn how to load it into the database first. Generally, PL/SQL is not a client-side language.

Comment: @defaultlocale - This I know haha! Still thank you for the note. Thats why i was reading about it in the first place, but I did not know if there is a different approach

Answer (score 0):

You could create an external table that reads the whole line in one long VARCHAR2. Then SELECT from this table, read the first line, and you get a string with the column names. Stick this string inside a 'CREATE ...' statement and execute it.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I was actually trying something similar, but lets see if I will make it work :)